# Material-Ui theme issue with React components imported from a library (via yarn workspaces)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, yarn-workspaces

I am running into an issue ([similar one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201655/material-ui-theming-issue-with-react-components-imported-from-a-library/67703825#67703825)) with yarn workspaces. I understand that there are two copies of Theme context and for some reason the rendering of the component from library is changing the order of applied classes.

Its the same set of classes which apply to header in both the cases.. i.e.

classes while rendering a HomePage (or test-component) in MAIN-APP

> MuiPaper-root MuiAppBar-root MuiAppBar-positionFixed
> MuiAppBar-colorPrimary makeStyles-appBar-2 makeStyles-appBarShift-3
> mui-fixed MuiPaper-elevation4

classes while rendering a component-1 from LIBRARY-COMPONENTS

> MuiPaper-root MuiAppBar-root MuiAppBar-positionFixed
> MuiAppBar-colorPrimary makeStyles-appBar-2 makeStyles-appBarShift-3
> mui-fixed MuiPaper-elevation4

Like stated above by [@Jerome in the mentioned issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201655/material-ui-theming-issue-with-react-components-imported-from-a-library/67703825#67703825), .MuiAppBar-colorPrimary gets applied first giving it the required background-colour whereas in the other case (loading from library) .MuiPaper-root gets applied first overriding background-colour and creating the issue

How can I fix / troubleshoot this further?

Btw, structure of apps in my case

REPO

- MAIN-APP
  -- HomePage
  --- HEADER (containing AppBar)
  --- FOOTER
  --- CONTENT (having ...)
  -- test-component
- LIBRARY-COMPONENTS
  -- Component-1
- LIBRARY-UTILS
  -- Theme (using createMuiTheme)

(for yarn workspaces)

- node_modules
- package.json